# How can I speed up the load time of my script that uses require statements?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, require

I switched from using Crack to Nokogiri to parse short XML-like strings.

I am not sure if that is the cause of it, but it appears to now take 4 minutes to load my script versus 20 seconds.

It's hard to isolate the cause because I made some changes to the code, but when I put time-stamps into my logs, it is the load time from using `require` statements for gems and `require_relative` statement for the associated script.

Since I run these on worker instances, each time the script is called, it must load the associated files, and so this dramatic increase really affects performance.

1. Could Nokogiri be particularly slow in loading?
2. What suggestions are there to speed it back up to the earlier rate?

ADD: I got some additional information from the vendor providing the worker instances.  This raised a question which may answer this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802760/does-nokogiri-rebuild-itself-with-a-require-statement

Comment: What is 20 seconds for?

Comment: You're asking us to diagnose a problem with your code, especially load times, without telling us a thing about the code that could cause slow load times, and you didn't give us a sample of the code. It's out of our scope to guess what the problem could be. Please fix your question and give us an example of the code that demonstrates the problem. As is you asked a very generic and broad question, so we really can't give you a better answer than "It's in your code." I load apps using Nokogiri in sub-second times, so it's not Nokogiri. Perhaps your machine is underpowered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could nokogiri be particularly slow in loading?

Possibly, but not 4 minutes slow just to require Nokogiri.

For example, on my laptop `require "nokogiri"` takes 1 second.

When you time something in Ruby, use the `benchmark` module.

> It's hard to isolate the cause because I made some changes to the code

These steps may help you isolate the cause:

1. Launch `irb` then `require "nokogiri": _____ seconds

   ```
   require "benchmark"
   time = Benchmark.measure do
     require "nokogiri"
   end
   puts time
   => 0.040000 0.020000 0.060000 (0.092582)
   ```
2. Launch your original script as is, without processing any XML:  _____ seconds
3. Add the benchmark code above to your original script, then  launch as above: _____ seconds
4. Deploy the trivial benchmark script to your worker and run the script: _____ seconds

   ```
   require "benchmark"
   time = Benchmark.measure do
     require "nokogiri"
   end
   puts time
   ```
5. Log the timing within your new script: _____ seconds

   ```
   require "logger"
   logger = Logger.new("example.log")
   logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
   logger.debug("The logger debug is working")

   require "benchmark"
   time = Benchmark.measure do
     require "nokogiri"
   end
   logger.debug("require nokogiri time: #{time}")
   ```

> What suggestions are there to speed it back up to the earlier rate?

1. Use the Ruby `benchmark` method around sections of your code.
2. Add `logger.debug` statements to ensure your app is doing what you expect.
3. What does the `ps` command show you (or use your monitoring tool of choice) for the amount of RAM used? RAM free? CPU load?
4. What does the `lsof` command show you (or use your monitoring tool of choice) for the files that are opening during launch?
5. Do you know `dtrace` and if so, what do dtrace probes turn up?
6. Can you daemonize the script in some way, so the script is always loaded?

Comment: I run the code on a worker, so it spins up each time...my local environment is fine, but then everything is already there....I use `time ruby response.rb` where `response.rb` is the file being run and loaded in the worker and it's fine.

Comment: Thanks. Could I keep the code and run it in the worker task to benchmark the times?  Or this something I could only do from IRB?  Thanks this is a great way to diagnose.

Comment: You can use your existing new code, because you can add logger.debug statements. I added more info to the answer for you about logger.debug.